# Kotlin - Iterate through array

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I have an array like this and I would like to loop through it and get the value "B". I know how to get it in Java but I have no idea how to get it in Kotlin. Could someone show me how to do this?

private val myArray = arrayOf({"A";"B"},{"C";"D"})

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I don't think this array does what you think it does. Currently its an array of 2 functions, the first of which returns "B" and the second "D". A and C are completely ignored. Could you please post your complete Java code (array and loop) that you want to convert? Also note that IntelliJ or Android Studio can convert Java to Kotlin automatically.

Comment: Actually, I used myArray for storing first name and last name. This is my code in Java         for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            String[] element = myArray[i];
            //I do something here like println(element[0])
        }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{}` is not a valid operator to create array in kotlin you've to use `arrayOf()` instead. In kotlin `{}` is reserved for creating lambda funtions.

You could iterate over the array like this:

```kotlin
private val myArray = arrayOf(arrayOf("A", "B"),arrayOf("C", "D"))

for (innerArray in myArray) {
    for(element in innerArray) {
        println(element) // or your logic to catch the "B"
    }

}
```

Comment: You misspelled println.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with just one Loop

```
   val arr: Array<Array<String>> = arrayOf(arrayOf("A", "B"), arrayOf("C", "D"))
   for (arr2: Array<String> in arr) {
      val contains: Boolean = arr2.contains("B")
      if (contains) {
           println(arr2)
           break
       }
     }
```